# Need Reactjs help on how to properly pass this function from the parent to child button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

Brand new to reactjs so bear with me. 
 - I have a MovieContainer component that returns a table. 
 - I have a child MovieCell component which will be placed inside the MovieContainer and iterated over an array of objects. Inside the cell is a delete button that will filter the list array to remove the clicked item 
 - I have the the delete function prepared in the MovieContainer component but I'm not sure the proper way to pass it to the child.

[github link](https://github.com/aalokt89/vidly/tree/master/src/components)
MovieContainer Component:

```
class MoviesContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      movies: getMovies()
    };

    this.deleteMovie = this.deleteMovie.bind(this);
  }

  deleteMovie(movie) {
    const movies = this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id);
    this.setState({
      movies: movies
    });
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <MovieCell
              key={movie._id}
              title={movie.title}
              genre={movie.genre.name}
              numberInStock={movie.numberInStock}
              dailyRentalRate={movie.dailyRentalRate}
              deleteMovie={this.deleteMovie}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

MovieCell Component:

```
class MovieCell extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }

  handleDelete(movie) {
    this.props.deleteMovie(movie);
  }

  render() {
    const title = this.props.title;
    const genre = this.props.genre;
    const numberInStock = this.props.numberInStock;
    const dailyRentalRate = this.props.dailyRentalRate;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td>{genre}</td>
        <td>{numberInStock}</td>
        <td>{dailyRentalRate}</td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={movie => this.handleDelete(movie)}>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you passed it properly. What is the problem you are having? Ah, you can pass the `movie` to the child and then in your `handleDelete` you can use it again. Or you can use `id` insdtead of movie.

Comment: Thanks! yup passing in the id was the way to go

Comment: You are welcome. And, just look the code @Tholle provided. You don't need to invoke your `handleDelete` function, just use its reference. Like this way, it does not recreated in every render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently naming the `event` to `movie` and using that as your movie object which will not work as expected.

You could instead pass down the movie id as a prop and use that instead of the `event` when you call `handleDelete`.

```
class MoviesContainer extends Component {
  // ...

  deleteMovie(movieId) {
    const movies = this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movieId);
    this.setState({
      movies: movies
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <MovieCell
              key={movie._id}
              id={movie._id}
              title={movie.title}
              genre={movie.genre.name}
              numberInStock={movie.numberInStock}
              dailyRentalRate={movie.dailyRentalRate}
              deleteMovie={this.deleteMovie}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class MovieCell extends Component {
  // ...

  handleDelete() {
    this.props.deleteMovie(this.props.id);
  }

  render() {
    const title = this.props.title;
    const genre = this.props.genre;
    const numberInStock = this.props.numberInStock;
    const dailyRentalRate = this.props.dailyRentalRate;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{title}</td>
        <td>{genre}</td>
        <td>{numberInStock}</td>
        <td>{dailyRentalRate}</td>
        <td>
          <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```